# Migrate sitecore media library to DAM and update the media links in Sitecore

Tags: content-hub

We have installed the Content Hub connector in `Sitecore 10.2` with `Content Hub 5.0`.
Now there is one requirement from the client that all the media available in the Sitecore should be migrated to the Content Hub DAM and then all the Sitecore links should follow the Content Hub media's URL after migration.

So, does someone have any idea of how to migrate the media to the Content hub and then update the references of media in Sitecore fields to follow the DAM media's URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export Media files in CSV format and upload them into the Content hub.

Step 1:

Sitecore Media Library Export to CSV:PowerShell extensions script to help export the media library assets file names and path to a spreadsheet.

```
    $everythingUnderMediaLibrary = Get-Item master: -Query 
    "/sitecore/media library//*" 
    $outputFilePath = "C:\Media_Library_Export.csv" 
    #Create an empty csv file and paste the path here $results = @();    $everythingUnderMediaLibrary | ForEach-Object {
     $properties = @{
        ItemID = $_.ID
        Name  = "$($_.Name)"
        ItemPath = "$($_.ItemPath)"
        Extension  = "$($_.Extension)"
        Title  = $_.Title
        Alt_text  = $_.Alt
        Template = $_.TemplateName   }
     $results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties 
     }    
     $Results | Select-Object ItemID,Name,ItemPath,Extension,Title,Alt_text,Template | Export-Csv
    -notypeinformation -Path $outputFilePath
```

For reference : https://madhuanbalagan.com/migrate-sitecore-media-library-assets-to-dam

Step 2: Create Taxonomy in Content hub Instance
Create Taxonomy/ Option List as per business requirements in Content hub.

[image]

Step 3: Update Excel data as per Taxonomy
Update Column name in the exported sheet as per Taxonomy name

Update all data in excel according to the Taxonomy's value Identifier. For example:

[image]

[image]

Also, Rename the Name of Excel sheet (Name should be always "M.Asset")

[image]

Step 4: Upload Assets in Content hub through Import Excel

[image]

Step 5: Install Connector in Sitecore Instance (as per Sitecore version and content hub instance version)
Before installing the Connector Package, you need to add Sitecore url in Content hub Settings.

Go to Manage > Settings > Portal Configuration > CORSConfiguration

See below example:

[image]

After Installation of Connector in Sitecore instance, you can see new browser link "Browse Sitecore DAM".

[image]

Step 6: Run PowerShell Script in Sitecore to change the pointing URLs of images / Rich Text

Step 7: Check new URL in Sitecore
Now you can search any Image /PDF /Rich Text item. The URLs should be changed and pointing to Content hub URL.

For Example:

[image]

Sitecore Path: /sitecore/content/Global/Components/Rich Text/IND Get Started/Tools and Resources

New URL: https://ch-p-001.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/public/content/e9df763864af41ba8ecf6ed2e1f525ea

Old Sitecore URL: https://sitecoreinstance/-/media/sitecore/pdf-documents/individual/1848831_gettingstarted_ind_id.ashx

For reference: https://www.altudo.co/insights/blogs/how-to-migrate-assets-from-sitecore-media-library-to-content-hub

Comment: don't forget to mention the original content : https://www.altudo.co/insights/blogs/how-to-migrate-assets-from-sitecore-media-library-to-content-hub

Comment: @VladIobagiu yeah I did, thanks

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I did not understand the part of the answer about how the script will check the media reference available in the Sitecore field is to be replaced with which media in the Content Hub

Comment: if you are moving all the assets to Content hub then you can simply create a Powershell script replace the url to Content Hub media asset URL, as initial url will be same for all the assets (the hostname)

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I followed the approach but not sure in your answer what is the use of the zip downloaded using Powershell script and how uploading the Excel can upload the asset.

Comment: okay, you don't need zip file, you just need to download an Excel file using powershell script then you can upload that zip file using this link as well - https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/manage-digital-assets--import-assets-with-excel.html, you need to see what fields you need in Content hub, accordingly you need to create fields in Asset Schema.

Comment: Okay you mean upload the Excel file using the link you provided, right?