# Import excel component not visible in Content Hub for creating bulk assets

Tags: content-hub

I followed the article [Migrate sitecore media library to DAM and update the media links in Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/migrate-sitecore-media-library-to-dam-and-update-the-media-links-in-sitecore) for importing the assets in the Content Hub using the excel file but when I reached the step to import the excel then I got to know that I was unable to see the `import excel` option in my content hub.

Later on, I followed the https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/configure-content-hub--creation.html link to configure the import excel component but I see the following screens and nowhere I can configure the import excel option.

[image]

Then I don't see the expected result for adding the required component, but I see the following screen:

[image]

FYI: I am using `Content Hub 5.0`

Comment: Import Excel is configured in Creation Component. We can add a Creation Component and toggle the Import Excel option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also import Excel files from the Products section as well, following the steps -

1. Click on **Products** from Menu

[image]

2. Then click on the **+ Add** button

[image]

3. Click on the **Import Excel** button

[image]

4. Import your required excel here -

[image]

Make sure the Excel sheet name should be "**M.Asset**"